# linux tree command include head content of file

Tags: linux, bash

i need to create file raport with tree command .. including head content of each file, example current command :

```
tree -hF

├── [129K]  219.137.24.130
│   └── [125K]  gibi_gibi_member.csv
├── [5.7M]  219.142.104.84
│   ├── [ 43K]  xshop_unihongbaorecord.csv
│   ├── [ 18K]  xshop_zdmemberaddr.csv
│   ├── [2.2M]  xshop_zdmember_copy.csv
│   ├── [2.6M]  xshop_zdmember.csv
│   ├── [7.5K]  xshop_zdmembertelinfo.csv
│   └── [877K]  xshop_zdshareusersubmitinfo.csv
├── [9.9M]  219.84.203.57
│   ├── [259K]  wealth_e_newsletter_subscriptions.csv
│   ├── [ 59K]  wealth_orders.csv
│   └── [9.6M]  wealth_users.csv
```

i want this output :

```
├── [9.9M]  219.84.203.57
│   ├── [259K]  wealth_e_newsletter_subscriptions.csv
                ./head 219.84.203.57/wealth_e_newsletter_subscriptions.csv
│   ├── [ 59K]  wealth_orders.csv
                ./head 219.84.203.57/wealth_orders.csv
│   └── [9.6M]  wealth_users.csv
                ./head 219.84.203.57/wealth_users.csv
```

how i can do this ?

Comment: are you looking for the full path for each file, e.g. `tree -hFf`?

Comment: @gregory I believe he wants to execute the `head` command.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0):

This is very easily done using a combination of `awk` and `tree`:

```
tree -hFf | awk -v n=4 '1
                       { file=$NF; sub($NF"$","");gsub(/./," "); 
                         for(i=1;i<=n;++i) {getline var < file; print $0 var}
                         close(file) }'
```

here `n` indicates how many lines of the file should be printed.